# overwrite file and echo to stdout

Tags: bash, shell-script, tee

I have a simple bash function to increment a number and store it in a file:

```
get_next_int (){
   my_file="$HOME/next_int.json"
   touch "$my_file"
   typeset -i my_num=$(cat "$my_file")
   echo "$((++my_num))" > "$my_file" | tee
}
```

regarding this line:

```
echo "$((++my_num))" > "$my_file" | tee
```

out of curiousity, is there a way to overwrite the file with the incremented integer and echo it to stdout?

this answer about tee doesn't seem to cover my case.

[How to redirect output to a file and stdout | Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/418896/how-to-redirect-output-to-a-file-and-stdout)

also, as an aside, regarding this line:

```
typeset -i my_num=$(cat "$my_file")
```

that will grab the integer representation of the string from the file. However if the file is empty, I need to default to 1.

Is there a way to do something like:

```
typeset -i my_num=$(cat "$my_file" | default "1")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
echo "$(( ++my_num ))" | tee "$my_file"
```

Tee writes te the named file(s) and to standard output by default.

After `typeset -i my_num=$(cat "$my_file")` (which could be `typeset -i my_num=$(<"$my_file")` in `bash`), you could use

```
my_num=$(( my_num == 0 ? 1 : my_num ))
```

to set it to 1 if it's value is zero. Integer variables in `bash` evaluate to zero if empty.

I *was* going to suggest `my_num=${my_num:-1}` but since `my_num` is an integer variable, it will expand to zero if it's empty, not to the empty string, which means that the `${variable:-value}` parameter substitution would not work (this would otherwise expand to `value` if the variable was unset or empty).

---

I would probably have written the function as

```
get_next_int () {
    local -i val
    read val <"$HOME/next_int.json"
    val=$(( val == 0 ? 1 : val ))
    printf "%d\n" "$(( val + 1 ))" | tee "$HOME/next_int.json"
}
```

assuming `"$HOME/next_int.json"` always contained a single integer. I've left out the `touch` because the files modification timestamp would be updated by `tee` (keep `touch` if you need the access timestamp updated as well).

Comment: does that overwrite the file?

Comment: I assume so, and thank you, also if you have thoughts about the aside question, that helps

Comment: @AlexanderMills It does, unless `tee -a` is used for appending.

Comment: got it, any idea how to use a default string if cat comes up with empty stdout?